# Typescript check it type includes undefined

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to check if a type includes 'undefined' type?

```
type a = boolean | undefined;

type v = a extends undefined ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

I tried with extends, but it doesn't work.

Comment: And your name is `undefined`, that all makes sense now. :D

Comment: @RyanLe `interface undefined extends Human`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use conditional type with extra generic parameter

```js
type a = boolean | undefined;

type IsUndefined<T> = undefined extends T ? true : false

type Result = IsUndefined<a> // true

type Result2 = IsUndefined<number | string> // false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UBGB7FAbCMB2UA%20UArtgCYQBmAlthCQNwCwAUM6JFAJIDOAqqRdVoAeACoA%20BEX5UaJKBAAewCKS5QRUAPxRgAJ0LQAXFHIx0XCM1bhoAJQhdC6YJO58yM4TAkB6Hzv1LFiY2OwcnYAAmV15pQRIhbEIAWyQIXXwoLj1qAHNff1NzCCA)

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type ([distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)). For example, take the following.

If we plug a union type into `IsUndefined`, then the conditional type will be applied to each member of that union.

```js
type IsUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? true : false

type Result = IsUndefined<string> | IsUndefined<undefined> // boolean
```

`IsUndefined<string>` returns `false`
`IsUndefined<undefined>` returns `true`

Hence, `Result` is `boolean` because a union of `true` and `false` is a `boolean`.

**But**, if you put `undefined` before `extends` then conditional type will be applied to the whole union

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain why it works?

Comment: you just had them backwards, it's `undefined extends a` instead of `a extends undefined`

Comment: @undefined sure, give me a minute